# Laravel 4 query

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

Is it possible to execute something like this in Eloquent?

```
SELECT (SELECT `name` from `players` WHERE `player_id`=`id`) AS `name`, `value` FROM `player_skills` WHERE `skillid`=0
```

Comment: did you even bother to use SO search or read the docs before asking this question ?
http://four.laravel.com/docs/queries#selects
http://four.laravel.com/docs/eloquent#eager-loading

Comment: @Gadoma Yeah I did, didn't see that. Thanks;p

Comment: get yourself acquainted with the Basic, Query builder and Eloquent ORM  chapters from the docs. It will help you understand Laravel 4 better, and solve other of your problems listed on SO. Regads,

Answer (score 0):

This looks like just a simple relationship, so you can do something like this:

```
PlayerSkill::with('Player')->where('skillid',0)->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply run your query like this

```
DB::raw('SELECT (SELECT `name` from `players` WHERE `player_id`=`id`) AS `name`, `value` FROM `player_skills` WHERE `skillid`=0');
```

OR

```
DB::statement('SELECT (SELECT `name` from `players` WHERE `player_id`=`id`) AS `name`, `value` FROM `player_skills` WHERE `skillid`=0');
```

OR

```
DB::select('SELECT (SELECT `name` from `players` WHERE `player_id` = ?) AS `name`, `value` FROM `player_skills` WHERE `skillid`= ?', array('id', 0));
```

Best of luck :)